# Hide label in TableViewCell when swipe to delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to be able to hide a label in my `UITableViewCell` in order to stop it from overlapping with the title whenever a user swipes to delete a cell.

I'm using the following code to initiate and handle the swipe to delete:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Avoid  NSInternalInconsistencyException

        // Delete the project object that was swiped
        Project *projectToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", projectToDelete.name);
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:projectToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

        // Delete the (now empty) row on the table
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [self performFetch];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

I've assigned the label in the cell using:

```
UILabel *projectDate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    projectDate.text = project.dateStarted;
```

And have tried just setting

```
projectDate.hidden = YES;
```

however, this does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll need to subclass `UITableViewCell` to implement this.  In the subclass override `- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated`.  In this method you can hide the label.  If you only need to hide the label for delete operations, then use `self.editingStyle` to conditionally hide the label depending on the editing style (aka: UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete).

Here are two examples. I prefer example two, it's easier.  But example one will let you replace text, which might be useful:

```
@implementation CellSubclass{
    NSString *_labelText; //only used in example 1
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
// Example 1, replacing the text value
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (editing && self.editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:3];
        _labelText = label.text;
        self.textLabel.text = nil;
    }  else if (!editing && _labelText){
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:3];
        label.text = _labelText;
    }
}

//Example 2 - hiding the view itself
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (editing && self.editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        [self viewWithTag:3].alpha = 0.0f;
    } else {
        [self viewWithTag:3].alpha = 1.0f;
    }
}

@end
```

Please, please note that I have two methods with the same name.  That obviously is a big no-no....use only one of them.

Also note that I ignored the animated parameter.  If you want the disappearance of your label to be animated in the second example (aka...fade away/fade in) all you need to do is surround your changes in an animation block, like so:

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3f animations:^{
            [self viewWithTag:3].alpha = 0.0f;
        }];
```

I don't think you can animate the first example.

Comment: Hi, I do grasp the concept of subclassing the UITableViewCell, however would you please be able to provide a small example?

Comment: Yeah I'll edit my answer...give me a minute. Ok, answer edited.

Comment: Nice work (can't upvote you twice unfortunately) but your examples need a bit of tweaking - you should call the super implementation of setEditing, and you should also take the `animated` parameter into account - e.g. animate the disappearance of the label.

Comment: @jrturton Ah, yeah, good catch about super.  I'll edit it.  I just threw the example together so it will definitely need more work.  I did ignore the `animated` parameter on purpose.  It's technically not needed (though visually appealing) and it adds a little bit of complication to an answer I'm hoping to keep simple.  But I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: I thought you'd abandoned simple when you went for the alternative text example ;-). It's a great answer, mine is redundant now so I've deleted it.

Comment: @AaronHayman thanks for the answer! I'm going for example 2 to try it out, however I'm getting an error "Property editingStyle not found on object of type ProjectsController". This method should be able to access the editingStyle defined in my first question code, right?

Comment: @LordSnoutimus editingStyle is only valid for the class (or subclass of) UITableViewCell.  The error you're getting is telling you that you're trying to access the property that's not defined on the class of the object you're accessing...in other words.. on a class that isn't a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: Ah, you're right! it's not. It's actually a subclass of CoreDataTableViewController. Is there another method I could use?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  A UITableViewCell (or subclass thereof) is what all table view controllers use for their cells.  You have to subclass UITableViewCell, implement the methods I described, and use that subclass in your table view controller.  That's the only way as far as I'm aware of.

Comment: Aaron, I really appreciate your help with this, would you be able to provide an example of this? I think Im already subclassing UITableViewCell as I'm already using the variable editingStyle in my first code example. It doesn't add up to me!

Comment: @LordSnoutimus In your UITableViewController subclass, there is a method: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.  Normally you instantiate a UITableViewCell here.  Instead you need to instantiate your subclass of UITableViewCell in that method and return it instead of the standard UITableViewCell.  When a cell goes into editing mode, the `- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` you overrode in your subclass will be called.

Comment: Aaron, can't thank you enough. I understand what you meant by subclassing now, and have implemented your method. Works like a charm. :) thanks!